# Decrease excecution time of a nested for loop in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I am writing an objective function for one of may papers. It needs a nested loop as follow:

```
for j=1:m   
    if j==m        
        for i=1:n           
            consumedE(j) = consumedE(j)+ b(i,j)*e(i,j);
            for k=1:m-1
                for l=1:n                   
                    consumedE(j) = consumedE(j) + b(i,j)*(et(end)*Data(i).Vin);                    
                end                
            end          
        end
    else
        for i=1:n
            consumedE(j) = consumedE(j) + b(i,j)*(e(i,j)+et(j)*Data(i).Vout);
        end
    end
end
```

Where m and n are something about 200.

it is very time consuming even on a very powerful PC. How can I speed it up?

Comment: Please provide sample inputs, or at least mention the size of all vectors/arrays/structures involved. See [mcve].

Comment: You can speed up by using [vectorization](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) of your code. Matlab is not C, and is more efficient at accessing and operating vectors and matrices using vectorized operations instead of loops.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loops you don't refer to your inner indices at all.

```
        for k=1:m-1
            for l=1:n                   
                consumedE(j) = consumedE(j) + b(i,j)*(et(end)*Data(i).Vin);                    
            end                
        end
```

This should be identical to:

```
consumedE(j) = consumedE(j)+ (m-1)*n*b(i,j)*(et(end)*Data(i).Vin);
```

I would expect this to boost performance significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some random sample data. I simplified `Data(i).Vout` to a vector `DataVout`. You can easily do that with `[Data.Vout].'`. The same goes with `Data.Vin`.

```
m = 10;
n = 5;
b = rand(n,m);
e = rand(n,m);
et = rand(1,m);
DataVout = rand(n,1);
DataVin = rand(n,1);
```

Now, your else clause is a loop through all `i` and `j`, where you do the following for each combination:

```
b(i,j) * ( e(i,j) + et(j) * Data(i).Vout )
```

and then you sum over all `i`'s. You can do that in a vectorized fashion with the following steps:

1. The matrix multiplication `DataVout * et` creates a matrix containing `et(j) * DataVout(i)`. This matrix has size *n-by-m*, which is the same size as `e` and `b`.
2. Add `e` to this matrix, and do an element-wise multiplication between the result and `b`. This is: `b .* (e + DataVout * et)`
3. Sum over all rows: `consumedE = sum(b .* (e + DataVout * et), 1)`.

The last value, `j==m` is special in your calculation: you repeat the inner calculation `n * (m-1)` times, as you don't use `k` and `l` in any calculation. This results in

```
b(i,j) * ( e(i,j) + n * (m-1) * et(j) * Data(i).Vin )
```

which is identical to the previous calculation - except that `Data.Vout` is replaced with `n*(m-1)*Data.Vin`. *(Are you sure this is correct?)*
We can simplify the previous calculation, as we only do it for a single, fixed `j=m`, which leads to
`sum(b(:,m) .* (e(:,m) + n * (m-1) * DataVin * et(m)), 1)`.

Everything together, your entire code becomes:

```
consumedE = sum(b .* (e + DataVout * et), 1);
consumedE(m) = sum(b(:,m) .* (e(:,m) + n * (m-1) * DataVin * et(m)), 1);
```

A comparison: for `m=200` and `n=150`, your code takes `0.109523 seconds` on my machine. The vectorized code takes `0.005665 seconds`, which is a speed-up of factor 20.